# iCloud rejecting emails sent via smtp with error 550 5.7.0

Tags: email, smtp, icloud, mobileme, msmtp

I'm trying to set up msmtp with a MobileMe/iCloud account. I have 2 other accounts set up, and they both work just fine. But with the MobileMe account, I'm getting an error:

```
msmtp: server message: 550 5.7.0 From address is not one of your addresses.
```

This is crazy, because the from address provided is absolutely my address. I've entered it in multiple times just to be sure, same error each time. I'm kind of at my wits end here. Any ideas on how to debug this? Is there a chance that MobileMe is rejecting emails sent from non-applemail clients?

Answer (score 0):

TURNS OUT: msmtp was just failing when trying to perform a simple test from the command line. Once I sent an actual message from mutt, the email was sent without issue. Not sure why it was giving me that specific error message, but it was incorrect.